# UTM: Which terms for web application?

Tags: html, reactjs, web, architecture, utm

We are trying to find which correct UTMs to use. Example, we have 4 areas in a React web application that all direct to the our partner company ElectronicsStore website.

In Screen Page 1 ([www.abccompany.com/Home](http://www.abccompany.com/Home)), we have

1. LeftMenu,
2. Top Navigation Menu,
3. side ClickAd.

In Screen Page 2 (different area of application, [www.abccompany.com/Email](http://www.abccompany.com/Email)), we have it next to Email Inbox

All four lead to a ProductElectronics website. This is what I have so far.

I was thinking of using utm_content,  however  not sure since , they are not in the same rectangular section, but different areas of the screen.

```
utm_source: 'home-dashboard' , or 'email'
utm_medium: 'website'
utm_campaign
utm_term
utm_content
```

Should I use `utm_content:, and write ('left-menu', 'top-menu', 'click-ad', 'email-center'?` Would all this make sense for UTM Terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you're distinguishing between distinct app locations that lead to the same destination.

Left Menu:

```
utm_source=your_app_name
utm_medium=referral
utm_campaign=product_electronics
utm_content=left_menu
```

TopNavigationMenu:

```
utm_source=your_app_name
utm_medium=referral
utm_campaign=product_electronics
utm_content=top_navigation_menu
```

etc...

Please keep in mind that the 'utm_medium' parameter might be "referral" (or whatever you wish to call this form of navigation within your app).